# Lock scrolling in python console

Tags: python, scroll

How i can lock scrolling in python console? I print several lines to console and I don't want to user can scroll window up or down. Is there any library/command that can allow me to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Esthetic purposes

Comment: you are doing something wrong if restricting the user is equal to a increase in the perception of beauty.

Comment: solved by command `os.system("mode con lines=" + bufferSize)`

Comment: Well if python console only means "windows" it would have been easier... Even if I still don't think its a good idea. And your code does not work and will probably crash on any other operating system.